# From design to code

Tags: html, css, layout, web

I am currently struggling at creating a website from a given design. 
The design is created with InDesign and will be a one page website. The website has a width of 1280px. 
The main problem is resizing, because the design has diffrent layers. Some images consume the whole width and some are centered with a given size and when I resize the browser the elements scale diffrently. Is it possible to put the whole page in a container and position every element absolute (as its done in the design) and then just resize the container. So the page would resize like a image. 
 
 Are there some techniques in which I could read in? 
 
Here the backlayer uses the whole width and the circle is centered with a given size. Now if I resize the window the beckground scales with a diffrent ratio then the circle.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background-image now supports multiple images. You could try play around with that. But note browser support needs catching up.

EG

```
#example1 
{
background: url(img_flwr.gif) right bottom no-repeat, url(paper.gif) left top repeat;
}
```

Depending on your layout, images etc, it may be easiest to just use an editor to combine into one image.